# QCalendarWidget on year click using pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qcalendarwidget

How to fire mouse click event on clicking in year option for QCalendarWidget.

[image: encircle image]

onclick of year(2012), 
i want to print some text using pyqt5
Can anyone help. Thanks in advance/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing is to obtain the QSpinBox that shows the year using findChildren, then it is to detect the mouse event but as [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16295393/6622587) points out it is not possible so a workaround is to detect the focus event:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.calendar_widget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.calendar_widget)

        self.year_spinbox = self.calendar_widget.findChild(
            QtWidgets.QSpinBox, "qt_calendar_yearedit"
        )

        self.year_spinbox.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.year_spinbox and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.FocusIn:
            print(self.year_spinbox.value())

        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```